# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (Sqlite code 0): Native could not create new byte[], (OS error - 0:Success)

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

Hello I am getting this strange error in my app. The first time the application starts it runs however when I store a photo from the camera the app crashes and shows this log. The app takes photo from the camera or gallery and saves them in the database and displays the photo in a custom gridview.

```
                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad/com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad.CameraMainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (Sqlite code 0): Native could not create new byte[], (OS error - 0:Success)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
                                                                                        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (Sqlite code 0): Native could not create new byte[], (OS error - 0:Success)
                                                                                           at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
                                                                                           at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:403)
                                                                                           at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
                                                                                           at com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad.DatabaseAdapt.cursorToImage(DatabaseAdapt.java:179)
                                                                                           at com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad.DatabaseAdapt.loadAllImages(DatabaseAdapt.java:162)
                                                                                           at com.example.notepad.isidorosioannou.notepad.CameraMainActivity.onCreate(CameraMainActivity.java:48)
```

Here is part of the code from my db Helper and actually the methods that i get the error in the log.

```
public static final String CAMERANOTE_CREATE = "create table " + CAMERANOTE_TABLE + " ( "
        + CAMERA_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + CAMERA_TITLE + " text not null, "
        + CAMERA_DESC + " text not null, "
        + CAMERA_PATH + " blob);";    

public long createCamera(DataImage image){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CAMERA_TITLE,image.getTitle());
    contentValues.put(CAMERA_DESC,image.getDesc());
    contentValues.put(CAMERA_PATH,image.getPath());
    long insert= sqlDB.insert(CAMERANOTE_TABLE,null,contentValues);
    return insert;

 public ArrayList<DataImage> loadAllImages(){
    ArrayList<DataImage> imageList= new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(CAMERANOTE_TABLE,new String[]{CAMERA_ID,CAMERA_TITLE,CAMERA_DESC,CAMERA_PATH},null,null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        DataImage image = cursorToImage(cursor);
        imageList.add(image);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return imageList;
}

public Cursor loadAllTasks (){

    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TODOLIST_TABLE,new String[]{TODO_ID,TODO_TEXT,TODO_CHECKED},null,null,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}

private DataImage cursorToImage(Cursor cursor){
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapt.CAMERA_ID));
    String text = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapt.CAMERA_TITLE));
    String desc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapt.CAMERA_DESC));
    byte [] path = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapt.CAMERA_PATH));
    DataImage image= new DataImage(id,text,desc,path);
    return image;
}

}
```

Here is my main activity:

```
public class CameraMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ImageView buttonImage;
private GridView gridView;
private ArrayList<DataImage> imageList;
public  DatabaseAdapt dbAdapter;
private CameraAdapter cameraAdapter;
private AlertDialog alertBuilder;
private Uri imageUri;
private Bitmap bitMap;
private byte [] byteArray;
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE=2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    buttonImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cameraOptionButton);
    buttonImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewPhoto);
    dbAdapter = new DatabaseAdapt(getApplicationContext());
    dbAdapter.open();
    imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    imageList = dbAdapter.loadAllImages();
    cameraAdapter = new CameraAdapter(this,imageList);
    gridView.setAdapter(cameraAdapter);
    createAlertWindow();
}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    dbAdapter.close();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId()==R.id.cameraOptionButton){
        alertBuilder.show();
    }
}

private void createAlertWindow(){

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new  AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.alert_title)
                .setItems(R.array.alert_dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if(which==0){
                            activateCamera();
                        }
                        else{
                            chooseFromGallery();
                        }
                    }
                });
    alertBuilder = alertDialog.create();
}
private void activateCamera(){
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE);
}
private void chooseFromGallery(){
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){
        Bundle extra = data.getExtras();
        bitMap = extra.getParcelable("data");
        byteArray = convertToByte(bitMap);
    }
    else if(requestCode==REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        bitMap = decodeUri(imageUri,400);
        byteArray=convertToByte(bitMap);
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,CameraSaveActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("byteImage",byteArray);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private Bitmap decodeUri(Uri image,int size){
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(image),null,options);
        int width = options.outWidth;
        int height = options.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true){
            if(width/2<size || height/2<size){
                break;
            }
            width /=2;
            height /=2;
            scale *=2;
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options options2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(image),null,options2);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private  byte[] convertToByte(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,b );
    return  b.toByteArray();
}
```

}

and here is my second activity where I just preview the image and save it.

```
public class CameraSaveActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText cameraSaveTitle , cameraSaveDesc;
private ImageView cameraPreview;
private Button saveButton;
private byte [] byteArray;
private DatabaseAdapt adapt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_save);
    cameraSaveTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cameraEditTitle);
    cameraSaveDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cameraEditDesc);
    cameraPreview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
    saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveCameraButton);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    byteArray = intent.getByteArrayExtra("byteImage");
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    cameraPreview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream));
    adapt = new DatabaseAdapt(this);
    adapt.open();
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v.getId()==R.id.saveCameraButton){
        String text1 = cameraSaveTitle.getText().toString();
        String text2 = cameraSaveDesc.getText().toString();
        DataImage image = new DataImage(text1,text2,byteArray);
        adapt.createCamera(image);
        finish();


    }
}
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    adapt.close();
}
```

}

Can someone please help. I searched but I could not find a solution

Comment: Please add the statement how you create the table. It seems like there is a mismatch between the declared dataType in the column and the value the cursor is trying to parse..

Comment: Hello thanks for your time. I have edited my question and added the create statement

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are storing path in CAMERA_PATH, which is string and trying to get a Blob. There is a type mismatch and thats why the error is thrown.
You need to insert a blob in the CAMERA_PATH before you try retrieving a blob from there.

Comment: no I am not. I am storing a byte array, See here in my second activity:  DataImage image = new DataImage(text1,text2,byteArray);
        adapt.createCamera(image); The path is just the name of the variable that remained from a previous implementantion I have tried.

Comment: I have also print the byteArray to ensure that I am storing bytes. It gives results like this : [B@e802303. I have also made static the instance of the dataHelper that I use in the first activity because I thought maybe it was a problem that I created a new instance of the helper in the second activity but the problem still remains